# Why does (2-methoxyethyl)benzene undergo nitration at the ortho position (major product)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, nitro-compounds, electrophilic-substitution

This is an option in a question in which we needed to mark all the correct reactions:

> [image: nitration of (2-methoxyethyl)benzene]

According to the answer key, this is a correct option.

As an alkyl group is directly bounded to the benzene ring, I thought that the reaction will have para product as the major product.

I have a similar doubt with the nitration of toluene. I am unclear as to why ortho product is the major product.

It's be highly appreciated if anyone could please explain the reasons behind the major products of both the reactions.

Comment: Inductive effect is distance dependent and thus the electron density at ortho position will be greater than that at para position.

Comment: Ok, but I considered hyperconjugation (because it is more dominating than inductive effect), and then steric hinderance factor - so due to hyperconjugation, the group will be ortho-para directing, and then to avoid steric hinderance, the major product would have been para product. I read that in case of ethyl and other bulkier alkyl groups on the benzene ring, para product is the major product.

Comment: The positions are similarly activated - you get more ortho product because there are 2 ortho positions and only 1 para position.

Comment: Alright, but then why are the major products of nitration of aniline, anisole, and other bulkier groups on benzene para products